# form radio button not passing value

Tags: php, html

I am failing to see why a small form with a radio button group fails to pass any value to a processing php page. I have posted the code at pastebin.com at this link: http://pastebin.com/GT5HDpuc and would be grateful if someone could point out why this is happening. Thank you

UPDATED 
all code at http://jsfiddle.net/xGrb9/3/

Comment: Is there more code than what you're showing? I don't see any submit button/mechanism in your markup that would post the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have your radio buttons in a `<form>` element.

Encapsulate the radio buttons in the following:

```
<form method="post">
radio buttons go here

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: it is jquery form for the validation and php for the processing. there is a form element but no submit button that is handled by javascript

Comment: In that case, leave out the submit button portion of the code above. The radio buttons still need to be placed into a form element, however. Are you using AJAX to send the form's contents to the PHP script?

Comment: To clarify, is only the radio button group not passing a value to the PHP script? Or are none of the values being passed? Do you receive any output from the AJAX method?

Comment: only the radio buttons. i am getting response from ajax in firebug. in order to post radio button values i have to refresh browser. kinda weird

Comment: To be honest, I can't find anything else that would be preventing your PHP script from getting specifically the contact2 value. Try creating an array with the POST arguments in it and pass that through $.ajax's as the data parameter, maybe that will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put those inside a `<form method="post"></form>` element and you need to also submit the page to get the from the PHP side..

You example code does not show either of those things happening..